# Get an id from a dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datagridview

Can anyone help me with this. I have a table and I want that when I click a cell in it to get the row id (which would be the first column). Actually this is part of a project I am trying to do in which I need to display all childs of a parent. So I was thinking to get this id from the parent and then iterate through all the childs and verify which have the same id as a foreign key and then show them . Please help me with some ideas. I can provide code if you can't understand my question

```
public AirlineReservation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();      
        }

        private void getData()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter parentDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Airline", connection);
            parentDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Airline");
            SqlDataAdapter childDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Plane", connection);
            childDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Plane");

            DataColumn parentColumn = ds.Tables["Airline"].Columns["airline_id"];
            DataColumn childColumn = ds.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];

            rel = new DataRelation("PlaneAirline", parentColumn, childColumn);
            ds.Relations.Add(rel);

            parentBindingSource.DataSource = ds;
            parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Airline";
            childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childBindingSource.DataMember = "PlaneAirline";   
        }

        private void AirlineReservation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource;
            getData();  
        }

        private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable airlines = ds.Tables["Airline"];
            foreach (DataRow airline in airlines.Rows) {
                Console.WriteLine("AirlineID = " + airline["airline_id"]);
                Console.WriteLine("AirlineName = " + airline["name"]);
                DataRow[] planes = airline.GetChildRows("PlaneAirline");
                Console.WriteLine("This airline has following planes:");
                foreach (DataRow plane in planes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  PlaneID = " + plane["plane_id"]);
                }
            }           
        }
```

I have made the relation between the 2 tables and so far when I click a cell it shows me all the childs and their parents. But I want to show only the childs of the selected cell.

Comment: Please help me with some ideas :(

Comment: In dg_CellContentClick your outer foreach loop is iterating over all rows - It's been long enough since I did anything with DataGridView that I can only offer advice rather than a solution, but I would start by looking at dg.CurrentRow within that event handler and see if you can't use that to get to the subset of data you need.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I think sender will be a DataTable Row.  You just have to cast it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains members to get the clicked row and column index. By that you can determine the clicked cell and get it's data. That should make you able to get the corresponding planes.

```
private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked row: " + e.RowIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked column: " + e.ColumnIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("Cell value: " + dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
}
```